# RCircos - how to draw a single circular chromosome

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I want to visualize a chloroplast chromosome along with it's gene annotation and an expression histogram. Ideally my end result should look similar to this:

http://standardsingenomics.org/index.php/sigen/article/viewFile/378/982/8344

I'm trying to do it with the RCircos package for R, but I'm having a few difficulties. I've managed to run the tutorial commands and get a nice picture of the human chromosome. However, I'm having a problem drawing a circle with just one chromosome. Following the tutorial example, my whole chromosome looks like a small line instead of a whole circular molecule - as if it was a very small slice of pizza cut out from the rest. I've tried changing some settings, mainly "base.per.unit" but the best I could get is a hendecagon missing one side... Clearly not what I'm looking for. Sample of my input is as follows:

The cytoband file:

```
    Chromosome  ChromStart  ChromEnd    Band    Stain
1   chr1    0   79910   p36.33  gneg
2   chr1    79911   101303  p36.32  gpos25
3   chr1    101304  113909  p36.31  gneg
4   chr1    113910  135301  p36.23  gpos25
```

The first lines of gene names and coordinates:

```
    Chromosome  chromStart  chromEnd    Gene
1   chr1    14  1075    psbA
2   chr1    1642    3177    matK
3   chr1    4473    4700    rps16
4   chr1    6370    6441    trnQ-TTG
```

The first lines of histogram data:

```
    Chromosome  chromStart  chromEnd    Data                
1   chr1    1   25  3,007320953             
2   chr1    26  50  3,221414238             
3   chr1    51  75  3,36267093              
4   chr1    76  100 3,404491618
```

Is there any way to draw a circular molecule using the RCircos package with this data?

EDIT

I have managed to get almost a perfect circle by multiplying all coordinates by 1000 and changing them in a similar way in the other input files. However, I'm still unable to map histogram data. It seems like the track boundires are too low, and no matter how small my values are, they fill up the track completely. Unfortunately, I find myself unable to identify any setting that would change that.

Commands used:

```
Hist = ("Histogram.txt");
data.col <- 4;
side <- "in";
track.num <- 1;
RCircos.Histogram.Plot(Hist, data.col, track.num, side);
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
In Ops.factor(RCircos.Par$track.height, hist.height) :
  ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: This might be something ggbio could be used for, but I'm not very familiar with either RCircos or ggbio. It also looks like most of the data you are plotting is in a tiny fraction of the cytoband file. Am I reading this right, all your histogram values are in the first 100bp of the psbA gene?

Comment: These are just headers of my gene names and histogram data, I probably should have mentioned that. I have 134 genes in total and the histogram data goes up to 135k in 25bp intervals, covering the whole cytoband file.

Answer (score 4):

I made up a toy set of more complete data. I think this is pretty straightforward with `ggbio`.

```
 gr <- GRanges(seqnames = rep('chr1', 6), 
          IRanges(start = c(1, 500, 1000, 2500, 10000, 20000), 
                  end = c(499, 999, 2499, 9999, 19999, 30000) ), 
          strand = rep('*', 6),
          name = sample(c('A', 'B'), size = 6, replace =T ) )

 data <- GRanges(seqnames = rep('chr1', 100), 
            IRanges(start = sample(runif(100, min = 0, max = max(end(gr) ) ) ), 
                    width = 50), 
            d= runif(100, min = 0, max = 30) )
```

`ggbio` works a lot like ggplot, so you can build up pretty complicated plots. The vignette can be found [here](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ggbio/inst/doc/ggbio.pdf)

To build a circular plot like you are desribing this would work.

```
a <- ggbio() + circle(gr,  geom = 'rect', aes(fill = name), space.skip = 0.01) 
a + circle(data , geom  = 'bar', aes(y = d) )
```

The `space.skip` is particularly important for controlling how much space is between the end of a chromosome and the beginning of the next. 
[image]
The output looks pretty good, and different `geom` and `themes` can be added just like with ggplot.

I would add a bit of caution using circos style plots, sometimes the linear view is much easier to interpret.

Comment: Thank you very much jraab, this looks useful indeed. I think I'll try this method if I fail with RCircos. A question though: how would you add the names of the genes and histogram data (third table from my OP) to your example?

Comment: The `ggbio` docs are pretty extensive and you can use a variety of `geoms`. To place rectangles where the genes would be, you'd use `geom='rect'`, for the names themselves you'd use `geom = 'text', aes(labels=gene_names)` .